# Unity cannot destroy clones GameObject

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, photon

I am using Photon PUN for multiplayer and instantiating GameObjects (OtherCraft) from a prefab as players enter, and destroying them as they leave - or rather, the destroy doesn't work. The relevant code is as follows:

The prefab is loaded in Start(), and there is a dictionary to hold references to the instantiations as they happen (Other craft is simply a cube with mesh and script right now):

```
    OtherCraft
            otherCraftPrefab;

    Dictionary<int, OtherCraft>
            otherCrafts = new Dictionary<int, OtherCraft>();
    
    ....  //  the following in Start()

    GameObject
            tmp = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Prefabs/OtherCraft", typeof(GameObject));
    otherCraftPrefab = null;


    if (tmp == null)
        Debug.Log("Failed to load prefab for other craft");

    else
        otherCraftPrefab = tmp.GetComponent<OtherCraft>();
```

When a new entrant is a notified by an OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer), a new craft is created and added to the dictionary:

```
    OtherCraft
            otherCraft = Instantiate(otherCraftPrefab, new Vector3(0,1,0), Quaternion.identity);

    otherCraft.setActorNumber(newPlayer.ActorNumber);
    otherCraft.setNickName(newPlayer.NickName);

    otherCrafts.Add(newPlayer.ActorNumber, otherCraft);
    Debug.Log("Other craft instantiated - " + otherCraft.getNickName() + ", ActorNumber=" + otherCraft.getActorNumber());
```

The Debug.Log line shows it was all OK (`Created craft - OtherCraft(Clone) (OtherCraft): nick2, ActorNumber=2`), the right ActorNumber etc, and it shows up in the game view and hierachy OK.

When notified of player leaving by `OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player exPlayer)`, it references the entry in the dictionary and gets rid of it again:

```
    OtherCraft
            otherCraft = otherCrafts[exPlayer.ActorNumber];
    int     actorNumber = otherCraft.getActorNumber();
    string  nickName = otherCraft.getNickName();
    Debug.Log("Recovered craft - " + otherCraft.ToString() + ": " + nickName + ", ActorNumber=" + actorNumber);

    otherCrafts.Remove(actorNumber);
    Destroy(otherCraft);
```

Except it doesn't, it is still there in the game view and hierachy. The Debug.Log line also shows wrong information (`Recovered craft - OtherCraft(Clone) (OtherCraft): , ActorNumber=0`). It got the wrong thing back from the dictionary.

Cannot see what I have done wrong?

Comment: did you add a log if the `exPlayer.ActorNumber` is correct (should be `2` right?) Also the nickname seems to be empty ...

Comment: Thanks, yes, there was another debug line above which proved that, I just didn't include it. Empty nickname is the default. Actually I have solved it, see answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I have solved this. The `GameObject` - `OtherCraft` - has a script, also named `OtherCraft`. What actually got stored in the dictionary (and later removed and destroyed) was the instance of the script, not the `GameObject`.

It is kind of implied in a lot of the Unity community instructional docs, videos etc to keep the names the same - "create a `GameObject` '`Fred`', now add a script to it, named - why not - '`Fred`'". Well, that way can lie trouble. A lot of the time the two are interchangeable and you want access to the script anyway. They are nearly interchangeable, but it seems, not always. Not in this case anyway.

I changed it so the `GameObject` was `OtherCraftGo`, keeping the script as `OtherCraft`. The dictionary was changed to store `GameObject`s, and when needed, the script was accessed by `OtherCraft script = myOtherCraftGo.GetComponent<OtherCraft>()`.

Solved the problem. A salutory lesson, for me, anyway.

Comment: Yes `Destroy` if called with a component only destroyed the component. You could have sticked to your code by simply make it `Destroy(otherCraft.gameObject);` instead ;) would be more efficient than always using `GetComponent` again